# Is it possible to manually fetch `yield` values instead of in a loop?

Tags: crystal-lang

Taking this example from the docs, we can send a block that receives the `yield` values from the function.

```
def twice
  yield 1
  yield 2
end

twice do |i|
  puts i
end
```

What I'm wondering is if we can manually call on the function so that the first call gives `1` then we do other stuff, and then the next call gives `2`.

I tried (just guessing) various things, like `puts twice()` but to no avail. Is there any way this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use spawn and channels. This is the closest you can get:

```
def foo
  yield 1
  yield 2
end

chan = Channel(typeof(foo { |x| x })).new

spawn do
  foo do |x|
    chan.send x
  end
  chan.close
end

p chan.receive?
p chan.receive?
p chan.receive?
```

http://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/ijd

You could build an abstraction over that, maybe with macros:

```
def foo
  yield 1
  yield 2
end

macro enumerator(call)
  %chan = Channel(typeof({{call}} { |x| x })).new
  spawn do
    {{call}} do |x|
      %chan.send x
    end
    %chan.close
  end
  %chan
end

values = enumerator(foo)

p values.receive?
p values.receive?
p values.receive?
```

http://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/ije

And probably using a wrapper struct so it looks like an Iterator ( http://crystal-lang.org/api/Iterator.html ). But note that this is kind of slow, at least much slower than using an iterator or a regular non-captured block call.

Comment: Thanks for that interesting solution though it won't be quite right for my situation. Thought there may be some functionality like ECMAScript6 has with its generator functions but I can work around it. Thanks again!